# Why Stack Overflow repeatedly asks me if I'm a robot?

Tags: support, asking-questions, captcha

I'm an old enough user of the site and never got a question flagged as spam. I post regularly and have few threads locked. My IP doesn't change. Yet, almost every single time I post a new question, I see the following dialog:

[image: the box]

Why doesn't my user history convince the system I'm not a robot? In the case the user is old enough and never was flagged for spam, shouldn't the system know better than to constantly challenge?

Comment: Do you paste (most) of the question at once?

Comment: Yes, I do. That'd make sense, although now I feel observed.

Comment: Well, that usage-pattern happens to coincide with bots, and with duping content from elsewhere. Such happens.

Comment: I got a captcha twice within about 5 minutes yesterday, without even posting anything. The first time it was while just trying to pull down the notification dropdown. I don't think I had seen a captcha for at least a few months before. So I suspect that there might have been some recent malfunctions.

Comment: @Viclib Well the question is: Are you a robot? :]

Comment: Me? That is slander. Is that allowed? Moderation, attention, please?

Comment: Only a robot would say that.

Comment: We will remember that.

Comment: I find it does this if you draft your question offline and paste it. If you type too fast, it assumes you might be a bot. Which technically is true - you did use automation to make the post. I find the solution it - press answer before starting typing.